# How to switch columns rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have the following dataframe:

```
                                0       1
0                 enrichment_site   value
1                    last_updated   value
2                     image_names   value
3                 shipping_weight   value
4                        ean_gtin   value
5                        stockqty   value
6                      height__mm   value
7                    availability   value
8                             rrp   value
9                             sku   value
10                     price_band   value
11                           item   value
```

I tried with pivot table

```
test.pivot(index=index, columns='0', values='1')
```

but I get the following error:

```
KeyError: '1'
```

any alternative to pivot table to do this?

Comment: What is the desired result? What is the value of `index`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `df = df.T` to transpose the dataframe. This switches the dataframe round so that the rows become columns.

You could also use [`pd.DataFrame.transpose()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html).

Answer (score 3):

When using `pd.DataFrame.transpose` (as suggested by Jamie Bull), be sure to actually write

[`pd.DataFrame.transpose()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

...without the brackets, it didn't work for me.