# How to transpose datas in csv file using python

Tags: python

I have to transpose my csv file datas using python:

**Actual output:**

```
sen 1.2
zen 2.2
ben 3.3
```

**Expected output:**

```
sen zen ben
1.2 2.2 3.3
```

I want to get `sen`, `zen`, and `ben` to be displayed horizontally in a straight row and the values under it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Mate what is the input of your data? Could you please divide it to rows and collumns if you want an answer. Otherwise The df.T answer takes the transpose of your input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to switch columns rows in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658183/how-to-switch-columns-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Mate do you know what are you doing? The actual output and expected output are transpose of each other already.

Answer (score 1):

To transpose a dataframe:

```
df = df.T
```

Answer (score 1):

If data is in numpy matrix use

```
numpy.transpose(matrix)
```

If data is in Pandas use

```
df.T
```

For any other format you have to use loops

Refer the link
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transpose-matrix-single-line-python/][1]