# How to reshape the date using values of a column as column names in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, python-requests

I have this data:

```
        index       2020-08-26 16:20:00  2020-08-26 19:09:00    2020-08-26 20:04:00
0       start       230                  104                    64
1       stop        228                  185                    170
2       avail       None                 None                   None
3       Status      False                False                  False
```

And I want to convert it to this form:

```
    index                start   stop  avail  Status
0   2020-08-26 16:20:00  230     228   None     False
1   2020-08-26 19:09:00  104     185   None     False
2   2020-08-26 20:04:00  64      170   None     False
```

I have applied

df.T

But I got an output as:

```
                    0       1       2        3
index               start   stop    endtime  status
2020-08-26 16:20:00 230     228     None     False
2020-08-26 19:09:00 104     185     None     False
2020-08-26 20:04:00 64      170     None     False
```

I want index, start, stop, endtime, status as column names

Comment: Just try transposing it `df.T`. You may first need to make your "Index" column as the index of your df `df.index = df['index']`

Comment: @ Anoop Sharma  Got it, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to switch columns rows in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658183/how-to-switch-columns-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @das-g  no see what I got.

Comment: @PriyankaS.Desai Check with `df = df.set_index('index').T`

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide code for the transition, but after it is made you can rename the columns:

```
df.rename(columns={"0": "start", "1": "stop", "2": "end time", "3": "status"})
```

And then delete the first row:

```
df.drop(df.index[:1], inplace=True)
```