# switching data set columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy

I have this data about income for every country from 1800 till 2040 :https://www.gapminder.org/data/
that looks something like this:

```
country  1800  1801  1802  1803
Albania  667   667   667   667  
Algeria  715   716   717   718
Andorra  1200  1200  1200  1200
```

I want to change to something like this:

```
country   year   income
Albania   1800   667
Albania   1801   667
Albania   1802   667
Albania   1803   667
Algeria   1800   715
Algeria   1801   716
Algeria   1802   717
Algeria   1803   718
.....
```

I have no idea from where to start

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is `transpose`. Both pandas and numpy can easily do that for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658183/how-to-switch-columns-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Just `melt` here

Comment: `df.melt('country')`